# Sheaf $\operatorname{Isom}(x,y)$ isomorphic to fibered product $U \times_{(x,y),X \times X, \Delta} X$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, algebraic-stacks, fibered-categories

$\DeclareMathOperator\Mor{Mor}\DeclareMathOperator\Isom{Isom}$Let $S$ be a scheme and $C$ be the category $(Sch/S)$. Let moreover $p:X \to C$ be an algebraic stack over $C$. Consider an arbitrary scheme
$U$ over $S$ and $x, y\in X$ be two objects lying over $U$.

We define the presheaf of morphisms from $x$ to $y$ as the
presheaf
$$(f: V \to U) \mapsto \Mor_{X_V}(f^*x, f^*y).$$

We call the associated sheaf $\Isom(x,y)$. Because we assumed $X$ to be
fibered in groupoids, $\Mor_{X_V}(f^*x, f^*y)= \Isom_{X_V}(f^*x, f^*y)$,
justifying the sugestive name choice.

**Question**: I saw several times in papers dealing with stacks that
the fibered product $U \times_{(x,y),X \times X, \Delta} X$
is canonically isomorphic to $\Isom(x,y)$ , but found nowhere
a rigorous proof of this statement.

Could somebody elaborate the proof of isomorphism? I'm talking purposely about 'the' proof (not 'a' proof) since seemingly this isomorphism
is estabished canonically without basing on additional sophisticated
constructions/choices etc.

Comment: Why do you say "the stack Isom(x,y)"? Isn't it just a sheaf of sets (over C/U)?

Comment: Yes, you are right, when I was writing this always when
 categories fibered in groupoids are involved I always have stacks in mind. 
Yes you are right $Isom(x,y)$ is of course a sheaf of sets over $C/U$.

Comment: This is not really about stacks: try to prove the above statement when X is a groupoid and U is just the one point set (note that you need to take the 2-categorical or homotopy fiber product in order to make it a true statement)

Comment: @DenisNardin: I think I understand the issue, let's try. Let 
$U = *$, $X$ the groupoid regarded as groupoid 
over $U$ and $x,y \in X=X_*=X_U$. By Yoneda we can 
identify $x,y \in Hom(U, X)$. 

Now we have to identify $Isom(x,y)$ to 
2-fibre product $U \times_{X \times X} X$ 
which consists of triples $(u, z, \alpha)$ where 
$u \in U, z \in X$ and isomorphism
$\alpha: (x,y)(u) \to (\Delta_X)(z)$.
Now since $u =*$ we have $(x,y)(u)= (x,y) \in X \times X$
and $(\Delta_X)(z)= (z,z)$.

Comment: Following approach to identfy 
 $U \times_{X \times X} X$ with $Isom(x,y)$ 
looks for me to be quite canonical, but I'm not 
sure to $100$ percent if that's 
exactly what the literature can in this setting 
canonical. Is this exactly the conventional
way to identify them:

Say we have an iso $\alpha: (x,y) \to (z,z)$ then we can
decompose it in two isomorphisms $a_x: x \to z$ 
and $a_y: y \to z$ and define $a_y^{-1} \circ a_x \in 
Isom(x,y)$ using identification $Isom((a,b), (c,d))= Isom(a,c) \times Isom(b, d))$. Obviously the construction is $1$ to $1$.

Comment: Is this 
exactly the construction sitting behind the word 'canonical'
in this context?

Comment: @GhostinGrothendieckuniverse Yes, this is the standard identification. Note that it's not exactly 1-1, rather it is an equivalence of groupoids (since $U\times_{X\times X}X$ has morphisms different from identities, although not in ways that matter)